# In MS Excel, how to find the title of a table in relation to a searched value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a simple table in Excel but I can't find the formula to apply to find the title of the column where the value I am looking for is located.

For example: here I would like the cell to display "Alpha Team" if I search for "Emma".
[image]

So my question is: How to display the title of a column of a searched valued in a matrix ?

Comment: `=INDEX(A1:D1,1,AGGREGATE(14,4,(A2:D4="Emma")*COLUMN(A2:D4),1))` to be entered as an [array formula](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula) if you don't have dynamic arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use array function as below:
=INDEX(A1:D1,SUMPRODUCT(MAX((A2:D4="Emma")*(COLUMN(A2:D4))))-COLUMN(A1)+1)

Comment: Emma is in column A but you reference with index() columns B to E?